# Snap points to nearest polylines within buffer (fast)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, snapping, speed

This is a working version of snapping any point to nearest polyline within a buffer distance. But, this takes significantly longer as each time it copies the point to a different shape and snaps it. Is there a way to create a faster version of this tool?

```
    for id in ids: #ids contain the list of links within the buffer
        where_clause = """ "_ID_" = %d""" % id
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(base_f, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause) #selects one/any link
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(other_pt_f, m1) #copies it to temp(m1)
        arcpy.Snap_edit(m1, [[base_f, "EDGE", "1 Miles"]]) #snaps the node to that link
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(m1, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as curs:
            for xy in curs:
                nearxy.append(xy[0])
    near_ids[key] = nearxy #gets the coordinates of the snapped point
```

Comment: `Snap_edit` takes a snap environment parameter where you can specify the distance.  Any reason why you can't just use that?

Comment: I have used the environment which is "EDGE" and "1 Miles"

Comment: I guess I'm asking how your current approach differs from setting that environment distance to the buffer distance you're interested in

Comment: If I use just that parameter, the node will be snapped to just 1 nearest link and the process would stop. However, here, the node would be snapped to all the links within the buffer.

Comment: Couple of thoughts. You may already have this but you don't show how the data is created. Setting up a spatial index or an attribute index can speed up the querying. Also when you are copying features you can use in_memory or a feature set and that will limit the writes to the hard drive.

Comment: I don't know how spatial index works but m1 is 'in_menory'. I am surprised how slow the process is. It takes almost 1 second for one point.

Comment: Run near tool. Use field calculator arcpy.Point(nearx,neary) on selected records. Run it on shape field.

Comment: Personally, I suspect the copy features is the slow point. Did you test to see which process takes the longest? You can also set an Index for _ID_ and that might speed up the SelectLayerByAttribute.